# UserVoice loads incomplete in Opera 11.60 on MacOS

Tags: javascript, html, macos, opera, uservoice

In Opera 11.60 on MacOS the UserVoice layover does not load completely. When I open it however with Opera 11.60 on Win7 32 Bit it loads without any issues, like it does in any other browser I tested.

Here is how it looks with Opera 11.60 on MacOS:

[image: uservoice on gruppenunterkuenfte.de]

That's the website: http://www.gruppenunterkuenfte.de/

The code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var uvOptions = {};
  (function() {
    var uv = document.createElement('script'); uv.type = 'text/javascript'; uv.async = true;
    uv.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'widget.uservoice.com/5Nw55SHakNb5M4MupIrEIQ.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(uv, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Do you have any idea, how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seams to be a bug in UserVoice itselfe.

Here is what a got from the support team:

Thanks for using UserVoice. We don't officially support Opera. However, our Developers are looking into this. Your code is fine. The Widget on our own website is messed up in Opera on MacOS too.

I'll let you know as soon as I hear something from them.

Comment: Hmm I just tested with Opera 11.60 and Opera 12 and it has been fixed indeed. For example on http://uservoice.com/widget/ Thanks for reporting the bug for us.